# jquery is blocked in IE when opened as file from a virtual-network-directory

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, activex

I have an HTML file with jquery script in it.

when opened as a file on my own computer it asks "Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls. Allow blocked content?" and when I press "Allow" it works fine but when in a virtual-network-directory it doesn't ask me and simply block it :-\

- I tried playing with the IE Settings unsuccessfully (if you think you
  know exactly what settings I need to change there I'd love to hear :) )
- I know I can drag it to my computer and run it but this is not an
  option (it's for a lot of people) and is being changed a lot.
- I don't care if it will ask this question when I open it from my
  virtual-network-directory or simply run it automatically.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "virtual-network-directory"?

Comment: And what version of IE are you using?

Comment: the file is in a server and its path is \\netapp1\dir1\dir2. if i want to access the file I write in cmd \\netapp1\dir1\dir2\myHtml.html
using the latest IE...

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt there is a way to "fix" this.  The problem is that if you can load an arbitrary javascript file from the user's filesystem -- and even more so from an arbitrary network location -- you can use that to load files from their system.  Thus, you generally cannot do this, nor should you be looking to make it possible as it could cause other issues.

What I would recommend is to look at what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Did you know that you can find simple standalone web servers that you can use to serve files from an arbitrary directory? I use node-static with node.js, but looks like [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) is another option that doesn't require much by way of dependencies.  At any rate, strongly recommend that you find another solution rather than actually trying to make the browser do dangerous things =]

Comment: I'm not loading any file from my script I'm just opening an html file that is in a virtual-directory...

Comment: the browser can't tell the difference